Identify horror movie involving morphing furniture
I remember watching the trailer for a horror movie years ago, I vaguely remember a scene where a group of young people were running away from something, closed a door, and then furniture in the room began morphing, maybe the door handle morphed into a snake or something like that. 
I'm not sure but I think it was a large house, maybe a mansion or castle. And maybe they were running away from a witch. 
I also believe the movie was made before 2010, maybe much earlier, but the morphing effect was CG so probably not made before the 90s. 

not much to go on. Where did you see the trailer? On TV? Was it a movie in the theater or some kind of Made for TV or B movie or straight to DVD?

I saw the trailer on TV

John dies at the end? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy83MPk7Wpg

I don't think that's it. It's probably a lot earlier than 2010, maybe 2004 or earlier.

The Haunting with Liam Neeson and Catherine Zeta-Jones has a whole house which animates, not just the furniture. Made in 1999.

probably duplicate of http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16860/horror-movie-where-the-house-comes-alive/17225#17225

It is Beetlejuice? When they are leaving the attic and the banister turns into a snake?



The furniture also morphed as well.




No I'm definitely sure that's not it, also the morphing was definitely a CG effect and not done using clay.

Of course it had to be the other Tim Burton movie, Dark Shadows. Part of the stairway morphs into a snake, the sculptures come alive and move, it is done with computer graphics, a witch is causing the magic and the boy runs away, and they are in a mansion which looks practically like a castle.






